# How do I add multiple linear-gradients to a css background? If

Tags: css, background-color, linear-gradients

I am trying to accomplish the left widget box below and as you can see, there is a diagonal linear gradient, as well as a shine from top to bottom. The one I created in CSS is to the right, while the one I am trying to accomplish is to the left. Is there a way I can accomplish this using only one background property? Or would I need to surround the entire div with another div so I can overlay a semi-transparent gradient on it? Thanks

[image]

UPDATED with code:

```
.drk-grad {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d2d2d2 7%, #b1b1b1 100%);
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 1px #969494;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 1px #969494;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```

SOLUTION:

```
background: repeating-linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.5) -1%, rgba(107, 107, 107, 0.1), repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, #b6b6b6, #B6B6B6 10px, #b2b2b2 10px, #b2b2b2 20px);
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Generally you can add multiple backgrounds, separated by commas. The first one listed will appear on top.

http://css-tricks.com/stacking-order-of-multiple-backgrounds/

http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/

Here's a basic outline. Play with the numbers for your exactly desired effect:

```
div {

    background: 
        linear-gradient(to top, transparent, #b1b1b1 100%),
        gray repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 35px,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 35px, 
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 70px);

    background-clip: padding-box;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 1px #969494;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
}
```

Demo: https://jsbin.com/fidaxigaxi/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Thanks for adding your code! I've created a basic demonstration of concept above.

Comment: in the demo, what is the part using `linear-gradient` ?

Comment: I don’t know what happened to the demo, so I made a new one now.