# how to create multiple linear gradient with different angle and colors

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients, repeating-linear-gradient

I am trying to create master card and i currently working on its back side but i don't know how to create multiple linear gradient like this.

The part behind the 1234567 numbers.

[image]

In my case i want to recreate those grayish to white to grayish into `linear-gradient(to right ,orange, lightblue, orange)`.

After seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831363/how-do-i-add-multiple-linear-gradients-to-a-css-background-if) question and i try to help me out with chat gpt but he doesn't understand what i was trying to say.

In this question there a [site](https://jsbin.com/fidaxigaxi/edit?html,css,output). when i try to change it's code things got little bit easier but i can't understand to how to change those gray line into right.

this is a code wrote to explain myself better.

```css
div{
width:100%;
height:300px;
background:#fff;
border: 3px solid #000;
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
flex-direction:column;
gap: 10px;
}

span{
width:100%;
height: 10px;
background: linear-gradient(to right, orange, lightblue,orange);
display:block;
}
```

```html
<div>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: you want the result result as the snippet you provided?

Comment: yeah by repeating it with css not adding multiple span like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two gradients:

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  background: 
    repeating-linear-gradient(#0000 0 10px,#fff 0 20px),
    linear-gradient(to right, orange, lightblue, orange);
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a tool like this to create your own gradient: https://cssgradient.io/

Instead of using multiple span tags you probably want to use multiple background rules, combined with child selectors, something in this direction:

```css
div{
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
  background:#fff;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  flex-direction:column;
}

div.card{
  width:100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(159,175,192,1) 0%, rgba(199,208,208,1) 33%, rgba(155,174,190,1) 67%, rgba(199,208,208,1) 100%);
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:flex-start;
}

span {
  width: 50%;
  height: 10px;
  background: black;
}

span:nth-child(2n) {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(159,175,192,1) 0%, rgba(199,208,208,1) 50%, rgba(159,175,192,1) 100%);
}

span:nth-child(2n - 1) {
  background: #dbe4eb;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="card">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i just created that code as an example to tell others what i want by repeating linear gradient.

Comment: I don't understand you. What are you trying to create here? 
From your question I thought it was a gradient like the one in the back of the MasterCard.

Comment: no don't mean the gradient of master card. i want the gradient of that "123456" strip where card number had written. those horizontal strip then a white again the gradient

Comment: check my update, probably the pseudo class :nth-child() will be enough to solve your problem.

Comment: that's ok if you don't have any other choices but using this much span is not good. anyway thanks for help.